# Trying to use file path's based on user within a cell formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a slew of IF, VLOOKUP, etc formulas with references to data from other worksheets within the same spreadsheets. I will eventually have many of these spreadsheets for each project I am running.

Instead of updating the referenced data in each, I will make one master spreadsheet with the referenced data and the project spreadsheets will reference that master spreadsheet for the data. The problem I have is that other users will use these project spreadsheets and the master spreadsheet will be located on a OneDrive sync'd to the users PC. Now I have to deal with different file paths within the formulas.

I found a VB script that will return the user's PC name. I can build a table that depending on the users name it will point to the right file path. I have tried the file path as a Defined Name but it doesn't work.

This formula works:

`=VLOOKUP('CTC Review'!F3&'CTC Review'!G1&'CTC Review'!A13,'C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Operations\Financials\CTC\CTC Data\[CTC Data Jan-19.xlsx]C2CDataExtractForLabor'!A2:M5000,7)`

What I am trying to get to work is:

`=VLOOKUP('CTC Review'!F3&'CTC Review'!G1&'CTC Review'!A13,'DEFINEDNAME & C2CDataExtractForLabor'!A2:M5000,7)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: %userprofile%/documents, etc., get you a non-login specific location

Comment: `INDIRECT` may help, but also may hinder if you have tons of formulas as it is volatile formula.

Comment: Cyril, Thank you for your response. I don't understand what you re referring to.

Comment: Scott, Thank you for your response.  The users wont have the data spread sheet open so INDIRECT won't work. But again, thank you for responding...